# How to apply new update trigger to all rows

Tags: sql-server

I created a simple trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[idlist_update] ON [dbo].[Store] 
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @brand varchar(50);
    DECLARE @model varchar(50);
    DECLARE @category varchar(100);
    DECLARE @part varchar(100);

    DECLARE @count int;

    SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM inserted;

    SELECT @brand=Brand, @model=Model, @category=AClass, @part=Descript FROM inserted;
    EXECUTE GenerateId_Part @brand, @model, @category, @part;
END
```

With rows, modified by our users (they using special application), it works ok, but I need to apply it to all rows in the table (more than 200.000+). I tried:

```
UPDATE Store SET lastupd={fn NOW()};
```

But it does not work.

Comment: So every time you insert or update a row in a table, you want to update ALL rows to show the current date/time? Why not store that information *once* elsewhere?

Comment: Also explaining what "does not work" means would be useful. Do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the syntax you want is:

```
UPDATE dbo.Store SET lastupd = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

However if you are updating the entire table every time you insert or update a single row, this seems quite wasteful to me. Why not store that fact once, somewhere else, instead of storing it redundantly 200,000 times? It seems to be a property of the store itself, not the products in it.

Also note that your trigger won't properly handle multi-row operations. You can't do this "assign a variable from `inserted`" trick because if two rows are inserted by a single statement, you'll only affect one arbitrary row. Unlike some platforms, in SQL Server triggers fire *per statement*, not *per row*. We can help fix this if you show what the stored procedure `GenerateId_Part` does.